# how to judege topological location of two nodes is of indifference in a simple graph?

Tags: graph, topology

I  wonder if there are some standards or conditions which can be used to

evaluate the topological location of nodes . As the sub image,

how to judge node 10 is indifference of 16 , 11 is equal to 15 and 12 is equal to 14 ?

[image: A sample image]